# Express router.post returns 404; router.get is fine

Tags: node.js, express, mern

=====

UPDATE and ANSWER:
I apparently missed changing the GET to POST in Postman. Not surprisingly, that solved the problem. Thank you all for your suggestions.

=====

Using Traversy's Udemy MERN class, but running into an issue with router.post().

Calling router.get works fine. router.post returns a 404.

Not sure why that is. Here are the relevant files:

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const app = express();

// connect DBase
connectDB();

// Init middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

// @route   POST api/users
// @desc    Register user
// @access  Public
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("User route server.js");
});

// Define routes

app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/api/users"));
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/api/auth"));
app.use("/api/profile", require("./routes/api/profile"));
app.use("/api/posts", require("./routes/api/posts"));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

db.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const config = require("config");
const db = config.get("mongoURI");

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(db, {
      useNewUrlParser: true
    });

    console.log("Mongo DB Connected...");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

users.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator/check");

// @route  GET api/users
// @desc   Test route
// @access Public


router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("post message");
});

module.exports = router;
```

POSTMAN OUTPUT: 404 Cannot GET /api/users

Totally confused. Thanks!

Comment: You are saying `router.post` not working and the output is `404 Cannot GET /api/users`. Is is the `router.get` not working or `router.post`?

Comment: I have made an example with your code and everything is working as expected. Only difference that i have is that i have only `users.js` routes being loaded and i have removed connectdb

Comment: @AritraChakraborty router.post isn't working.

Comment: error is saying GET, show a screen or something which shows your actually doing a POST..

Comment: Apparently, I didn't change the GET to POST in Postman. All works now. Oversight. Ooops. Thanks everyone, especially @LawrenceCherone for pointing me to my dumb error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could come from your filename : in your server.js you import a file named users and your file Users.js start by an uppercase letter.